# How do I paint the mesh just like in Paint.net?

Tags: texturing

I am new to Blender and I am trying to figure out how do I paint a mesh just like Paint.NET. I saw a menu called "Texture Paint" and it looks like the software mentioned above, but it doesn't let me paint the mesh, and displays the following warning: "Missing Textures, Detected!" What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use texture paint, there are a few steps you need to do. For this example, I am using a cylinder:

[image]

Step 1: UV Unwrap the mesh (You can find [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/index.html) or watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM) video):
[image]

Step 2: Add a new material and open the shader editor:
[image]

Step 3: Add an image texture node to your Material:
[image]

Step 4: Click new and create a new texture:

[image]

Step 5: Put the color output (Image texture) into the Base Color input (Principled BSDF):
[image]

Step 6: In the texture painting window, you should now be able to paint the textures!:
[image]

I would suggest watching Andrew Price's donut tutorial on YouTube as it covers ALL the basics of Blender. I NEVER watched it and I wish I did as a lot of problems I have had over the years of learning Blender, were covered in the video. [You can watch it here.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD)